# Apache redirect entire folder content

Tags: apache, redirect

I need to access to some static files in a folder from different domains. I've think that, instead of make several copies of that folder in each domain public folder, I could make some type of redirection or hard linking in apache for redirect them.

For example, I could access the common static files from `www.abc.com/static/*` and `www.def.com/static/*`, and internally, both urls point to the same folder "/home/static/*", transparently for the user and the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html).

What you want to do, however (creating an alias pointing to a directory outside the web root) needs to be done in the central configuration.

```
Alias /static /var/www/shared/static
```

Comment: thank you, it's a good solution, but do you think if exists another way of do it without change the central Apache config? By now, I do it throught a PHP proxy script that get the file that the user is looking for and loads its from the base path, but it has a poor performance

Comment: @Javier no, as far as I know, there is no other way to do this. You can use `Alias`  in `.htaccess` files too, but then you can't point to a target outside the web root.